# Fcm Push Notifications Not working on kitkat version

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Actually I'm working on FCM Push Notifications.In lollipop and above versions successfully worked but my application is kitkat and below versions are not working
and getting Error Like Unfortunetly Error, Application Stopped.anderror not showing in my logcat. Please anyone help me.

Comment: If you don't provide a piece of code, it's hard to help you

Comment: token generated?